# JQuery nested this references

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JQuery Code as follows:

```
$("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").live("click", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#sh-zone-cart-menu").toggle(0, function(){
        if($(this).is(":visible")){
            $(this).siblings(".sh-zone-button-link-menu-content").hide();
            $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").parent().removeClass("current");
            //need to reference (this) for $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu") here 
        }               
    });
    $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").parent().toggleClass("current"); 
});
```

I am trying to access the this reference for my initial click from within another sub-element i.e. I would like to get the this reference that would have been available just after the first curly brace of my live() method. However, I need access to it from within another sub-element i.e. inside my toggle() method.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm shocked this hasn't been up-voted more... you just saved me some time.  I didn't know that JavaScript lambda functions could capture local variables like this!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Save `this` as a local variable:

```
$("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").live("click", function(event) {
    // This line saves the current 'this' as a local variable 
    // that can be accessed by inner functions        
    var thisInClick = this;
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#sh-zone-cart-menu").toggle(0, function(){
        if($(this).is(":visible")){
            $(this).siblings(".sh-zone-button-link-menu-content").hide();
            $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").parent().removeClass("current");
            //need to reference (this) for $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu") here 
            $(thisInClick).doSomething();
        }               
    });
    $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").parent().toggleClass("current"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. This solved the problem. I just used var elem = $(this) and then called it where I needed to. Cheers.

Comment: Just getting into jQuery and ran into a similar problem. This concept just saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a watered-down sample to show you the general technique.

```
$("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").live("click", function(event)
{
    var that = this;

    $("#sh-zone-cart-menu").toggle(0, function(){
        alert($(that).attr('id'));
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save a reference to `this` in a variable, so you can use it later.

```
$("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").live("click", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var that = this;
    $("#sh-zone-cart-menu").toggle(0, function(){
        if($(this).is(":visible")){
            $(this).siblings(".sh-zone-button-link-menu-content").hide();
            $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").parent().removeClass("current");
            //need to reference (this) for $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu") here
            $(that).show(); // <= "that" is sh-zone-button-cart-menu
        }               
    });
    $("#sh-zone-button-cart-menu").parent().toggleClass("current"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the live callback, you have another method 'toggle'. The `this` keyword here refers to the specific element with ID of $('#sh-zone-cart-menu').

If you want to access that reference, simply use that selector.

Comment: The point is he doesn't want to have to select again since it was already available as `this`. No need to do extra work.